# Facing cursor lag on Chrome on laptop

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, cursor

I have recently been facing cursor lags when I'm scrolling and zooming on Google Chrome. It doesn't occur on any other app, neither on any other search engine. I tried looking for fixes, closed Chrome and restarted, but it didn't work. I'm on a laptop and don't use an external mouse.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may want to reset Chrome, and check the list of extensions. go to the settings of Chrome by copying and pasting “chrome://settings” into the address bar of Chrome and hitting [enter]
scroll to the bottom of the settings page you just opened to find the menu “Reset and clean up”

Comment: Is there no alternative,(sorry if I'm asking for much) but I don't want to lose on my history and stuff

Comment: BUMP!Please help..